# Is it possible in javascript to invoke "Object"

Tags: javascript

Do we have any ways to do in js something like this?

```
const pseudoFunction = {};
pseudoFunction();
```

Maybe add methods, constructor or something else to `pseudoFunction`?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? There is probably a better solution to your problem. All functions in JavaScript are objects for example.

Comment: Makes no sense, what are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: It`s just question, without any practical usage

Answer (score 4):

No.

Functions are objects, but not all objects are functions. You can only call functions.

You can see [the process for creating a function object in the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2). It is important to note step 3:

> Set the [[Class]] internal property of F to "Function".

You can't set that **internal** property yourself, so you can't convert a non-function into a function.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can not. You can try it out yourself, and you will get error.

```js
const something = {};
something();
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that with that what you're showing. You cannot call an object. But you can attach properties to functions (however, this is usually a bad pattern, you're trying to achieve something the wrong way).

```
let myFunction = function() { 
  console.log(myFunction.apples); 
  // Remember, _this_ here is not the function, but the caller scope
};

myFunction.apples = "oranges";
```

Once again, although this is doable, what you want to achieve is probably something that you could do in an idiomatic way.

Comment: I disagree that attaching properties to functions is a "bad pattern". It's quite common. The entirety of jQuery, almost, consists of properties attached to a function.

Comment: And who is using jQuery now? You're right, people who just try to crawl stackoverflow for how to add 2 numbers with javascript.

Comment: jQuery is almost certainly still the most widely-deployed library. There's simply nothing wrong about attaching properties to functions.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I just want to clarify is it possible to do something like __invoke in PHP using js

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can do the inverse: first create the function, then assign properties and methods:

```js
function doSomething() {
    console.log('done it');
}

doSomething.friend = 'John';
doSomething.printFriend = function() {
    console.log(this.friend);
}

// Make some calls:
doSomething();
doSomething.printFriend();
```